# Masking my IP for a game server

Tags: 16.04, server, minecraft

Hello!

Name's Bjorn. I am recently getting into server stuff and I really enjoy it I have done basic stuff in the past (set up a sftp server for my school included installing ubuntu. Did some other stuff.) anyways I want to get deeper and I know have my own personal server at my home.

I want to start a Minecraft server and make it public. I have run an MC server in the past, this time I want to host from home and it would be a good project and some nice server stuff practice for Mwah.

BUT

If it's public I don't want myself to be at risk for internet shenanigans, but I don't know where to start. If you can tell me what programs I can use along with what they do I can probably figure it out from there by using this forum and some other resources. My friend with more experience and less spare time then I said I should learn to mask my IP, hence the title of this question.

If this has already been answered then I apologize and a quick link would suffice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to conceal your source ip , you might want to look at [Cloudflare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlZf1.png) which basically makes your source ip hidden

its free and i currently use it for my domains

if you have a domain , which is basically a "name" for the website like google.com , then these instructions apply to you , i will be using the domain example.com , replace it with your domain , so

1. find a really obscure subdomain like asdfkjl.example.com and point it to your server address and untick the cloud like this -
   replace the 1.2.3.4 from the image with your real ip

[image]

2. make a srv record and follow the instructions in this gif to make it - 
   [image]

and then you are done!

Comment: Can you please explain how he can hide his IP behind Cloudflare?  As Cloudflare does not support port forwarding for Minecraft, this seems like an the wrong way to go.  He could use a non standard port I guess, but please elaborate on how he can do it. :)  Related: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Which-ports-will-CloudFlare-work-with-

Comment: If I did do this what would I give out for people to join the server? And would this protect me from people seeking to find my actual address. As well, my server is going to be running headless with no GUI so how and what would I do with all the Cloudflare things you are showing? Or is that not something I need to do on the machine itself like say a browser based  thing after I have the  system set up? Get back to me .

Comment: you would give you the SRV record as showed in the gif , if someone tried  tracing it , it would show a cloudflare ip somewhere in the world , also , you dont need to do anything on the machine , all the cloudflare stuff is browser based , you can do whatever  you want to do on the machine as if it was a regular minecraft server

Comment: @MukundB Alright Ill certainly look into it! Thanks.